# php doesn't have standard libraries, how to install 'em

Tags: php, docker, pecl

I got a docker image with php 8. I don't have any details about how it was assembled, but I need this image.

So, I ran it and picked into it (a docker image with php 8.1.25).

I need to install an extension here  with `sudo pecl install ***`  (*** any package it doesn't matter here) and I fail on it:

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootNiAoW5/EXTENSION-1.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/EXTENSION -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootNiAoW5/EXTENSION-1.0.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootNiAoW5/EXTENSION-1.0.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/EXTENSION -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /tmp/pear/temp/EXTENSION/EXTENSION.c -o EXTENSION.lo  -MMD -MF EXTENSION.dep -MT EXTENSION.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/EXTENSION -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootNiAoW5/EXTENSION-1.0.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootNiAoW5/EXTENSION-1.0.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/EXTENSION -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /tmp/pear/temp/EXTENSION/EXTENSION.c -MMD -MF EXTENSION.dep -MT EXTENSION.lo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/EXTENSION.o
/tmp/pear/temp/EXTENSION/EXTENSION.c:7:10: fatal error: ext/standard/info.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include "ext/standard/info.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:208: EXTENSION.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

With the docker-php install command `install-php-extensions ***` I have another problem:

```
tar (child): /usr/src/php.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I found this php version doesn't have standard libraries in there like:

```
base64.h                   credits.h         dir_arginfo.h   fsock.h        md5.h           php_crypt.h       php_fopen_wrappers.h    php_math.h      php_smart_string.h         php_versioning.h  url.h
basic_functions_arginfo.h  credits_sapi.h    dl_arginfo.h    head.h         pack.h          php_crypt_r.h     php_http.h              php_mt_rand.h   php_smart_string_public.h  proc_open.h       url_scanner_ex.h
basic_functions.h          crypt_blowfish.h  dl.h            hrtime.h       pageinfo.h      php_dir.h         php_image.h             php_net.h       php_standard.h             quot_print.h      user_filters_arginfo.h
crc32.h                    crypt_freesec.h   exec.h          html.h         php_array.h     php_dns.h         php_incomplete_class.h  php_password.h  php_string.h               scanf.h           winver.h
crc32_x86.h                css.h             file.h          html_tables.h  php_assert.h    php_ext_syslog.h  php_lcg.h               php_rand.h      php_uuencode.h             sha1.h
credits_ext.h              datetime.h        flock_compat.h  info.h         php_browscap.h  php_filestat.h    php_mail.h              php_random.h    php_var.h                  streamsfuncs.h
```

I tried to find them directly in source folder and by a command `sudo find / -name 'info.h'`  too, but system show no sign of it.

And when I copy and paste libs from other php installation in the source folder `/usr/local/include/php/ext/standard/` it finally works.

How can I bring libs there without copying 'em or linking a folder? May be is there a way to install it with other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is not "standard libraries", it is "code headers" - parts of the source code which aren't required for running the program, but are used when compiling other code that extends it.

The exact solution depends on what system your Docker image is based - Ubuntu, Alpine, etc, there's probably a package called something like "php-dev" which you need to install.

Comment: Thank you! This is true, php simply doesn't have php-dev package. I tried to install this with fresh ubuntu image and all header files appear there, but I can't do this with that image. It doesn't have any option even after system update.
Sorry, I forget that standard libraries are SPL libs, I have just seen on the path name and called it in the same way.
Thank you a lot for your answer and your patience!